# Javascript works in HTML but not in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

Code runs perfectly in HTML file, but when used in PHP file the javascript seems to be the only thing that fails. Does anyone know a reason why?

This code is supposed to make a  appear after a certain amount of time with out mouse movement. if the user moves their mouse, the  will .fadeOut();. However if the user doesn't move the mouse, then they are redirected to another url after a few more seconds.

```
 <html>
 <head>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $('#showdiv').fadeOut();

 var timedelay = 1;
 function delayCheck()
 {
 if(timedelay > 5)
 {
 $('#showdiv').fadeIn();
     if(timedelay == 12)
         {
                window.location = "https://www.google.com";
         }  
 timedelay = timedelay+1;
 }

 $(document).mousemove(function() {
 $('#showdiv').fadeOut();
 timedelay = 1;
clearInterval(_delay);
 _delay = setInterval(delayCheck, 900);
 });
  // page loads starts delay timer
 _delay = setInterval(delayCheck, 900)

  </script>

  <style type="text/css">
 #showdiv{
 width: 450px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 padding: 50px;
 border: 2px double gray;
 position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 40%;
 }

 </style>

 </head>
 <body>
      <div id="showdiv">
          <h2>
             You will be redirected in a few second unless you move your mouse.
          </h2>
       </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: F12, console. What are the errors?

Comment: You should do some proper code indention to make your code more readable and easier to follow.

Comment: What do you mean by "used in PHP file"? There is no php code here. How do you add php to this file or what kind of php code uses this code to produce output.

Comment: You're not closing your function. (you're missing the last `}`). This is a perfect example of how proper code indention would have helped.

Comment: I just noticed the missing brace thanks. It still worked when saved as a .html file. However, it needs to be saved as a .php file. F12 is not showing errors, it seems to just ignore all my javascript code.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're loading your jQuery functions at the top of the page you need to surround them with a document ready handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#showdiv').fadeOut();
     var timedelay = 1;
     function delayCheck()
     {
         if(timedelay > 5)
         {
             $('#showdiv').fadeIn();
             if(timedelay == 12)
                {
                    window.location = "https://www.google.com";
                }  
            timedelay = timedelay+1;
         }
     } // closing the function
     $(document).mousemove(function() {
         $('#showdiv').fadeOut();
         timedelay = 1;
         clearInterval(_delay);
         _delay = setInterval(delayCheck, 900);
     });
     // page loads starts delay timer
     _delay = setInterval(delayCheck, 900)
 });
 </script>
```

In addition, you're missing a closing bracket for your function.

Comment: This did work up until the first "$('#showdiv').fadeOut();". I just noticed the missing brace which is weird because it still worked in .html format. It still doesn't seem to catch mouse movement.

Comment: Anything in the console?

Comment: Nothing is showing in the F12 console. It seems to be completely ignoring javascript code. EDIT: I noticed on the last "_delay = setInterval(delayCheck, 900)" was missing a ";" but that didnt solve the issue.

Comment: Reduce the code to a `console.log()`. Or just reduce to the original fade. Make sure everything is working as expected with a couple of simple lines.

Answer (score -1):

You gotta understand that `JavaScript` is usually executed at the user's browser while `php` is usually executed in the server.

However, if you want to embed `JavaScript` on a `php` file, you can still do so after the last `?>` `php` tag.

Comment: The OP isn't asking to run JS-code _in_ PHP. Please look at the question again.